# Get previous and next list item id if has?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stuck on a point and need your some help friends. I need previous and next list. For example i have three li in a ul and this second one is active. Now i have to get previous and next li id. and if first li is active the don't do any thing also if last li then don't do any thing.

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">First <span class="testId">14</span></li>
    <li id="2" class="active">Second <span class="testId">15</span></li>
    <li id="3">Third <span class="testId">16</span></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery code i try but did not understand how to do this

```
if(){
            alert('good');
            /*var PrevTestId = $(this).prev('li').find('.testId').text();
            var thisId = $(this).next().find('.testId').text();
            alert(PrevTestId +" , "+ thisId);*/
        }
        if($(this).index() > 0){
            var PrevTestId = $(this).prev('li').find('.testId').text();
            var thisId = $(this).next().find('.testId').text();
            alert(PrevTestId +" , "+ thisId);   
        }
```

Comment: use `.prev()` and `.next()` with `.attr("id")` and `.hasClass()` this should be enough to solve the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask questions. You need to show some effort.

Comment: i already show my effort dear Darren Sweeney

Comment: `.find()` looks at child elements.  Your `li`s do not have child elements, so will not give any values.   `.testId` doesn't appear in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/1aL33df4/

```js
$('li').hover(function(){
   if( typeof $(this).prev().attr('id') != 'undefined')
    console.log("Previous Element ID: " + $(this).prev().attr('id'));
    if( typeof $(this).next().attr('id') != 'undefined')
     console.log("Next Element ID: " + $(this).next().attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="1">First <span class="testId">14</span></li>
    <li id="2" class="active">Second <span class="testId">15</span></li>
    <li id="3">Third <span class="testId">16</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use .next() or .prev() to get respective li
2. use .attr() to get the id
3. use hasClass() to test if li has active class

```js
var pliid = $("ul li.active").prev('li').attr('id');
var nliid = $("ul li.active").next('li').attr('id');

console.log("prev li id is " + pliid)
console.log("prev li is active " +  $("ul li.active").prev('li').hasClass('active'))
console.log("prev li textid text " +  $("ul li.active").prev('li').find('.testId').text())
console.log("next li id is " + nliid)
console.log("next li is active " +  $("ul li.active").next('li').hasClass('active'))
console.log("next li textid text " +  $("ul li.active").next('li').find('.testId').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="1">First <span class="testId">14</span></li>
    <li id="2" class="active">Second <span class="testId">15</span></li>
    <li id="3">Third <span class="testId">16</span></li>
</ul>
```